# Auto generating table

Tags: tables, loops

In the following scheme, why do I have to hide `&` in a macro (`\samp`) before it works?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\cptnewcounts{rowcnt,colcnt,maxrow,maxcol}
\def\docols{%
  \global\advance\colcnt\@ne
  \the\numexpr\rowcnt*\colcnt\relax
  \ifnum\colcnt=\maxcol\stopcol\fi
  \samp\docols
}
\def\stopcol#1\docols{\fi}
\def\samp{&}
\def\dorows{%
  \global\advance\rowcnt\@ne
  \global\colcnt\z@
  \docols
  \ifnum\rowcnt=\maxrow\stoprow\fi
  \scr\dorows
}
\def\stoprow#1\dorows{\fi\crcr}
\def\scr{\cr}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maxrow4 \maxcol3
$$\vbox{\halign{&\ \hfil#\hfil\strut\cr\dorows}}$$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\dorows` expansion is performed all in one swoop, generating the table body, and only then TeX will start to expand it looking for `&` and `\cr` tokens, if you hide them in macros. Otherwise TeX will see `&` and stop the column, inserting the *u* and *v* part, typesetting it and storing it away. So the dreaded `\endtemplate` token will find its way in the argument of `\stopcol`.

If instead you put `&` and `\cr` into macros, these won't be expanded until `\dorows` has finished its work and the table will be safely built.

Notice that `\cr` is *not* outer: the problem is exactly the same as with `\stopcol`, but with `\stoprow`.

You can see this by changing your input as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\makeatletter
\cptnewcounts{rowcnt,colcnt,maxrow,maxcol}
\newtoks\ahmed
\def\docols{%
  \global\advance\colcnt\@ne
  \global\ahmed=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\ahmed\the\numexpr\rowcnt*\colcnt\relax}%
  \ifnum\colcnt=\maxcol\stopcol\fi
  \global\ahmed=\expandafter{\the\ahmed\samp}\docols
}
\def\stopcol#1\docols{\fi}
\def\samp{&}
\def\dorows{%
  \global\advance\rowcnt\@ne
  \global\colcnt\z@
  \docols
  \ifnum\rowcnt=\maxrow\stoprow\fi
  \global\ahmed=\expandafter{\the\ahmed\scr}\dorows
}
\def\stoprow#1\dorows{\fi\global\ahmed=\expandafter{\the\ahmed\crcr}}
\def\scr{\cr}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maxrow4 \maxcol3
$$\vbox{\halign{&\ \hfil#\hfil\strut\cr\dorows\showthe\ahmed\the\ahmed}}$$
\end{document}
```

The `\show` command will output

```
> 1&2&3\cr 2&4&6\cr 3&6&9\cr 4&8&12\crcr .
l.27 ... \hfil#\hfil\strut\cr\dorows\showthe\ahmed
                                                  \the\ahmed}}$$
```

With this approach you *can* use `&` and `\cr`, because they would be protected by the braces of the token register assignment.

Comment: But the above result of `\show\ahmed` indicates that `$$\vbox{&...\dorows\the\ahmed}}$$` can't be a solution. It will inherit only the last (max.) values of the counters. I think you need to remove `\the\ahmed` after `\showthe\ahmed`, to indicate that you mean `$$\vbox{&...\dorows\showthe\ahmed}}$$` only as an illustration.

Comment: @AhmedMusa You are right, I forgot an `\expandafter`. Fixed.

Comment: Then you need to also replace the outcome of `\showthe\ahmed`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa I don't understand: the `\showthe\ahmed` shows the contents of the register, while `\the\ahmed` delivers it to the `\halign` for printing.

Comment: I have added something to the original question.

Comment: @AhmedMusa And isn't it what you wanted? I fixed the answer (forgot to change it after adding the `\expandafter`).